# Add a new line (\n) if a condition is met

Tags: r, text, rvest

I have made a web scraper by using rvest and created a data frame. One of the columns that I scraped has a lot of text in it and is hard to view.

The text in the column of my table looks like this,

```
Created 104 commits in 5 repositories raysan5/raylib 83 commits raysan5/raylib.com 17 commits raysan5/raygui 2 commits raysan5/rres 1 commit raysan5/raylib-games 1 commit , Reviewed 1 pull request in 1 repository raysan5/raylib 1 pull request Fixed #1455 Dec 13 , Started 1 discussion in 1 repository raysan5/raylib Welcome to raylib Discussions! Dec 8 , 2 contributions in private repositories Dec 18
```

Could someone help me find a way to add a \n after every comma (,) and perhaps remove the white space at the start of the next line? Also, it would be nice if a line can be skipped like shown in the desired layout. Moreover, if a bullet point can be added to each new paragraph that would be great too.

The text should be formated for example like this (desired layout),

```
Created 104 commits in 5 repositories raysan5/raylib 83 commits raysan5/raylib.com 17 commits raysan5/raygui 2 commits raysan5/rres 1 commit raysan5/raylib-games 1 commit

Reviewed 1 pull request in 1 repository raysan5/raylib 1 pull request Fixed #1455 Dec 13 , Started 1 discussion in 1 repository raysan5/raylib Welcome to raylib Discussions! Dec 8 

2 contributions in private repositories Dec 18
```

I hope I'm not asking for too much.

Answer (score 0):

[`gsub`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) can do that using a [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
gsub(' *, *', '\n', text)
```

`*, *` matches an arbitrary number of spaces, followed by a comma, followed by more spaces. And it replaces all that with the line break.

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't work, maybe because the text I want to format is saved as values, so if I use View(text) it shows in a table column with  25 rows and each row having text that needs to be formatted as I requested before.                                                                                            
                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                              so